# Почему письма отправляются через раз, так еще и с задержкой?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendmail

В общем такую ситуацию я уже наблюдаю достаточно продолжительное время, но сейчас накипело по этому поводу.

Переехал на DigitalOcean. Настроил сервер (Ubuntu 16.04.1 x64). Rails проект работает нормально, за исключением отправки почты с сайта.

Это касается не только моих кастомных Mailer'ов, но и Devise. Речь пойдет конкретно о Devise, так как это наиболее больная для меня тема.

У меня активировано подтверждение аккаунта по ссылке из email письма. Я сам лично регистрировался более 5-ти раз на сайте. Минут 10-15 я ничего не получал. В итоге я получил письма, но какие-то потерялись. Притом письма пришли не в том порядке, в котором я регистрировался.

После переезда код я правил только в production.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'http://site.com' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
```

Код кастомных Mailer'ов и уж тем более Devise я не трогал.

На сервер я ставил, разумеется Ubuntu Server. Но есть одно наблюдение из Ubuntu Desktop, которая установлена на виртуальную машину дома. На Ubuntu Desktop этой же версии письма с Rails проекта отправлялись моментально, хотя я даже не настраивал для этого ОС. Она была почти голой - только SSH, Ruby, gem's.

Comment: В логах есть чего?

Comment: @Majestio в логах все нормально. Письмо якобы ушло.

Comment: При передаче почты, скажем так, есть несколько зон ответственности. Ваша - ваше приложение, ваша - ваш sendmail, и "не ваша" - все остальное дальше. Если у себя вы не видите "косяков" в логах и не приходят отлупы о недоставке от провайдера - общайтесь с провайдером. Хотя, я бы еще раз перепроверил, погуглите а-ля "sendmail log verbose". Чтобы убедиться еще раз, набрать "позитивных" логов, и с провайдером разговаривать предметно.

Comment: Почтовый сервер какой используете?